# Firebase Database Function not working as it should on DialogFlow

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I'm writing a code for a chatbot and i'm having a problem with the database query on my firebase DB that I don't know how to fix, because it is the same as the other examples I found.

```
    var ref = admin.database().ref();
    var consultasRef = ref.child('consultas')

    agent.add('Test 2')

    consultasRef.on("value", function(snap){
        agent.add('Test 3')
        agent.add(snap.val());
    });
```

As said the function that should print the `snap.(val)`. It's not starting as it should. The right syntax is the same as the one I use. "Test 2" is being printed, unlike "Test 3", which is inside the function

For those unfamiliar with Dialogflow, `agent.add()` is the same as `console.log()` on JS, but for Dialogflow.

Answer (score 1):

When you make an asynchronous call (such as a database call), you **must** return a Promise from your Intent Handler so it knows when the call has completed so it can send the result back to the bot.

Additionally, you probably want to use the `once()` function, since you don't care about the database updating (since the result will already have been sent).

You can probably do both of these with code looking something like this:

```
return consultasRef.once('value')
  .then( snap => {
    agent.add('Test 3');
    agent.add(snap.val());
  });
```

There may also be issues with adding more than one or two text replies, depending on the Integration you're using.